# Focusing on inputs corrupts the page in Android Phongap

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to create a Phonegap app for Android, I'm not using any king of JavaScript frameworks like AngularJS or BackboneJS, everything is written vanilla.
When I focus on any inputs in the page - which is rendered properly - some parts of the page fade to white suddenly, and after I touch the screen or type anything in the input, the page gets back to its correct state again.

Why this happens and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

When you focus on the input, does the virtual keyboard gets displayed. If yes, it may be the viewport setting on your html. Did you try to prevent a page resize when input is on focus?